# unexpected token length error in css using netbeans`

Tags: css, netbeans

i have given height:35px in css,it works fine in linux text editor but shows error in netbeans.

```
#hori li
{
padding:0;
text-align:center;
width:7em; 
float:left;
list-style:none
height:35px;
margin-left:15px;
background:#38ACEC;
-moz-border-radius: 70px;
border-radius: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your `list-style:none` . Write like this `list-style:none;`.

```
#hori li
{
padding:0;
text-align:center;
width:7em; 
float:left;
list-style:none;
height:35px;
margin-left:15px;
background:#38ACEC;
-moz-border-radius: 70px;
border-radius: 70px;
}
```

Comment: silly mistake....thanks dude it is working now....i have another issue in linking my css fie in jsp page using netbeans..i have given the link code as
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cdcss.css" type="text/css"/>

Comment: @ksa - Sorry but comments are not the place to ask questions.